# Unable to run windows 2008 R2 after Disk2VHD

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I want to convert my physical domain control to hyperv, I created the VHD using Microsoft utility Disk2VHD,

The VHD was created, I attached it to HyperV and was able to login. After login the Virtual Machine shows me "Preparing your desktop" then I got empty screen with no response from the machine.

Please advice.

Sameh

Comment: Since you seem determined to P2V this instead of standing up a new one, as suggested by Mark and as is the better practice, [you might want to visit this technet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/06/10/how-to-virtualize-active-directory-domain-controllers-part-1.aspx).  It's got a lot of advice and links to resources that might help you do it "right."

Answer (score 2):

Don't P2V a domain controller. Just install a new DC, let the data replicate, transfer any roles if applicable, and demote the original DC.

Comment: Many thanks, but we have a very special situation so we need that solution. Any problem with P2Vding a DC?

Comment: @Sameh Well, there's this thread I saw somewhere about the Domain Controller hanging on an empty screen after `Preparing your Desktop` when he tried to P2V a domain controller...

Comment: Why is your "very special situation"? We are not mind readers. You should present all of the details of your problem when you are asking for help

Comment: Ok, @MDMarra sorry for missing details. Because there is a lot of configuration, SSL for domain installed for The SMS management from Microsoft, and Exchange server was installed on the DC and we don't have much resource to split servers. anyway, many thanks for your help, I reassigned 4 cpus for the new VM and wait about 15 mins then my server run normally. many thanks for your help